# Uxie is not appearing in Omega Ruby

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I know the requirements. I know you have to have 3 Pokémon at full happiness, and Uxie is supposed to appear between 8 and 9 pm. However, I've done all of this and she still hasn't appeared. I also reset my da time a few times to make sure it was right. It hasn't worked. Help.

Answer (score 1):

When you reset the time, they won't spawn for the next 24 real time hours.